# Uninstall opengeo suite in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boundless-suite

How can I properly uninstall the complete opengeo suite in my Ubuntu 12.04? I had installed opengeo suite but it seems there was some error in the PostGIS extension to the Postgres of the OpenGeo suite.

So I need to now reinstall it. What is the best and safe way to uninstall it properly and reinstall a fresh copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely remove the OpenGeo Suite, use:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove opengeo-suite
```

on the command line. I don't think Ubuntu 12.04 is officially supported by the OpenGeo Suite. You'd be better off using an older version. Or a VM if all you want to do is test it.

Comment: I am using VM. when u say packagename do you mean `opengeo-suite`?

Comment: Yup. My bad. I forgot the exact package name. Will fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

It's better off knowing what packages have been installed like so:

dpkg --get-selections | grep -v desinstall

I am not sure if you just remove the opengeo package and other other packages like the below will be removed:
opengeo-client, opengeo-dashboard, opengeo-docs, opengeo-server,...etc, in my case.

I have installed opengeo suite 4.5 but it doesn't have an opengeo-suite package.